# Getting an AttributeError: <class> has no attribute <method>

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am creating a method in a class in a module mod1 and calling it as follows:

```
class blahblah:
   def foobar(self, bvar, **dvar)
       ////
       return dvar
```

And calling it as:

```
obj1 = mod1.blahblah()
dvar1 = obj1.foobar(True, **somedictionary)
```

It throws a `Attribute error: blahblah has no attribute named foobar`

Could you please help me with it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Clearly, you have not posted the code that you're actually using, for whatever reason. That's fine. But based on your post, there's nothing wrong. Are you sure that there's not a typo in your real code (perhaps you accidentally spelled `foobar` as `fubar`, etc)?

Comment: No. I did check that and it wasnt typo for sure. Sorry didn't post the actual code because it is a security program.

Comment: This error can only occur if `foobar` is not a method defined inside `blahblah`. Since you assert that it is defined as such, you should not be seeing this error. Are you sure that `foobar` is defined inside `blahblah` in your real code?

Comment: Then you need to post your real code. There's absolutely nothing wrong with the code you've posted… wait! what version of python are you using?

Comment: Have you defined `blahblah` twice? Once with `foobar` defined, and once without? (i.e. overriding your previous definition)

Comment: @user1778309 please post the related excerpts from the real code.

Comment: Something you are assuming is true, is actually False. Take a look at `dir(mod1.blahblah)` (is `foobar` there?), `dir(obj1)` (is `foobar` there?), `obj1.__class__` (is it `mod1.blahblah`?), `obj1.__module__` (is it `mod1`?, etc.

Comment: worked for me this way.<br/>from mod1 import blahblah<br/> from blah blah import foobar<br/> obj1 = foobar()<br/>Thanks for your support all

Comment: @inspectorG4dget i am using python2.7

Comment: @user1778309: if that's what worked for you, then the code you posted does not represent the code you are working with at all; not in the least

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The type of error you describe can be caused simply by mismatched indentation.  If the method is at the very bottom of your class, move it up in the class a bit and the problem will become apparent.

When python interpreters run into mismatched indents (like say you started using tabs at the bottom of a file that was indented with spaces), the interpreter will not always throw an error; it can simply ignore the rest of the file.  I ran into this just today while updating some old code where the original author used different whitespace chars (that happened to match my Geany tabs), and it threw me for a loop for a lot longer than I'd like to admit.  :)

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I had the same issue where a mix of tabs and spaces were used for indentation in the file. I had read through a number of explanations without any resolution before finding your answer.

Comment: For what it's worth, it can also happen when using the %autoreload magic command in jupyter notebook, when you modify some methods in your module code (https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html#caveats)

Comment: This was helpful! Indentation was my issue as well.

Answer (score 6):

When I ran into this problem, I immediately started checking for unbalanced indents, tabs, etc... Everything seemed correct but the error continued to appear. I walked away, came back, took another look, and DUH..., I found that I had a typo. instead of `__init__()`, I had typed `__inti__()`. So check all of your constructor's syntax first.

Comment: I spent two hours until read this comments and gave it a try...
My method was called "def __int__(self):" and Pycharm didn't care. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, and for me it happened when I moved the class file, but I left a .pyo file in the old folder, and python was still reading that .pyo file instead of reading the moved .py file.

Answer (score 3):

Very old question, but I quote @Jacquot 's comment since it solved my problem (I was using %autoreload in ipython).

`For what it's worth, it can also happen when using the %autoreload magic command in jupyter notebook, when you modify some methods in your module code (ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/…)`

In particular, I solved the problem re-running the cell that was importing my class.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but for those who are facing this problem and none of the other answers could help you, this could be helpful. I was using **Pickle** to save an entire class with some data inside it, and loading this class instance again, but I had added some class methods and attributes on ****init****, that was why the interpreter couldn't find the new attributes described inside my class (It was loading the "old" class within the pickle object)

Comment: This turned out to be my issue. Was not paying enough attention to what I had pickled and when.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue until I realized I had named the classes in both the files with the same name - pretty dumb!

Comment: Are you sure that is the problem in the question?

Comment: I did not have the same problem - but did not find a solution too. Posted this, if someone else stumbles upon "MY" problem - they will find the solution in the same place.

Comment: This was exactly what I did - and worth mentioning, as Python doesn't error when you redefine a class.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For Jupyter notebooks using VSCode, what worked for me is to restart VSCode after changes to the imported file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just added ClassName to the method call, and it started working:

Wrong:

```
import Clases.Class_filename as LWD
articles=LWD.method_name(parameters)
```

Corrected:

```
import Clases.ClassName as LWD
articles=LWD.ClassName.method_name(parameters)
```

And the Clases/Class_filename.py contains something like this:

```
class ClassName :
    def method_name(parameters):
     ....
```