# sklearn transformation pipeline and featureunion

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I got a problem when trying run the following code. It's the machine learning problem of housing price.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin

num_attributes=list(housing_num)
cat_attributes=['ocean_proximity']
rooms_ix, bedrooms_ix, population_ix, household_ix = 3, 4, 5, 6

class DataFrameSelector(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self,attribute_names):
        self.attribute_names=attribute_names
    def fit(self,X,y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self,X,y=None):
        return X[self.attribute_names].values

class CombinedAttributesAdder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, add_bedrooms_per_room = True): # no *args or **kargs
        self.add_bedrooms_per_room = add_bedrooms_per_room 
    def fit(self, X,y=None):
        return self # nothing else to do 
    def transform(self, X,y=None):
        rooms_per_household = X[:, rooms_ix] / X[:, household_ix] 
        population_per_household = X[:, population_ix] / X[:, household_ix] 
        if self.add_bedrooms_per_room:
            bedrooms_per_room = X[:, bedrooms_ix] / X[:, rooms_ix] 
            return np.c_[X, rooms_per_household, population_per_household, bedrooms_per_room]
        else:
            return np.c_[X, rooms_per_household, population_per_household]


num_pipeline=Pipeline([
    ('selector',DataFrameSelector(num_attributes)),
    ('imputer',Imputer(strategy="median")),
    ('attribs_adder',CombinedAttributesAdder()),
    ('std_scalar',StandardScaler()),
    ])
cat_pipeline=Pipeline([
    ('selector',DataFrameSelector(cat_attributes)),
    ('label_binarizer',LabelBinarizer()),
    ])
full_pipeline=FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[
    ("num_pipeline",num_pipeline),
    ("cat_pipeline",cat_pipeline),
    ])
```

There comes bug when I trying to run:

```
housing_prepared = full_pipeline.fit_transform(housing)
```

And the error is shown as:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-141-acd0fd68117b> in <module>()
----> 1 housing_prepared = full_pipeline.fit_transform(housing)

/Users/nieguangtao/ml/env_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.pyc in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    744             delayed(_fit_transform_one)(trans, weight, X, y,
    745                                         **fit_params)
--> 746             for name, trans, weight in self._iter())
    747 
    748         if not result:

/Users/nieguangtao/ml/env_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.pyc in __call__(self, iterable)
    777             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    778             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 779             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    780                 self._iterating = True
    781             else:

/Users/nieguangtao/ml/env_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.pyc in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    623                 return False
    624             else:
--> 625                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    626                 return True
    627 

/Users/nieguangtao/ml/env_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.pyc in _dispatch(self, batch)
    586         dispatch_timestamp = time.time()
    587         cb = BatchCompletionCallBack(dispatch_timestamp, len(batch), self)
--> 588         job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    589         self._jobs.append(job)
    590 

/Users/nieguangtao/ml/env_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.pyc in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    109     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    110         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 111         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    112         if callback:
    113             callback(result)

/Users/nieguangtao/ml/env_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.pyc in __init__(self, batch)
    330         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    331         # arguments in memory
--> 332         self.results = batch()
    333 
    334     def get(self):

/Users/nieguangtao/ml/env_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.pyc in __call__(self)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

/Users/nieguangtao/ml/env_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.pyc in _fit_transform_one(transformer, weight, X, y, **fit_params)
    587                        **fit_params):
    588     if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 589         res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    590     else:
    591         res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

/Users/nieguangtao/ml/env_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.pyc in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    290         Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    291         if hasattr(last_step, 'fit_transform'):
--> 292             return last_step.fit_transform(Xt, y, **fit_params)
    293         elif last_step is None:
    294             return Xt

TypeError: fit_transform() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

So **my first questio**n is what causes this bug?

After getting this bug, I've tried to figure out why so I run the above transformers one by one as this:

```
DFS=DataFrameSelector(num_attributes)
a1=DFS.fit_transform(housing)
imputer=Imputer(strategy='median')
a2=imputer.fit_transform(a1)
CAA=CombinedAttributesAdder()
a3=CAA.fit_transform(a2)
SS=StandardScaler()
a4=SS.fit_transform(a3)

DFS2=DataFrameSelector(cat_attributes)
b1=DFS2.fit_transform(housing)
LB=LabelBinarizer()
b2=LB.fit_transform(b1)

result=np.concatenate((a4,b2),axis=1)
```

These can be executed correctly except that the *result* I got is a numpy.ndarray with size (16512, 16) while the expected result of `housing_prepared = full_pipeline.fit_transform(housing)` should be a bumpy.ndarray of size (16512,17). **So this is my second question Why causes the difference?**

Housing is a DataFrame with size of (16512, 9), only 1 categorical feature and 8 numerical feature.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The first error is due to `LabelBinarizer`. It requires only a single input y, but due to pipeline both X and y will be sent to it. Please share the data and I can help.

Comment: @VivekKumar Here's the link, it's the data of housing: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B12I2_fMO94pVHZhQlVrSlFtZEk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Why do you think that the result should have 17 columns instead of 16?

Comment: @VivekKumar Actually I also think it should be 16 columns. But this is actually an example on a textbook. The code  is theirs. They can successfully run the code that I cannot and they get a 17 columns result which I cannot understand.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like sklearn identifies datatypes in another way than you expect. Make sure numbers are identified as int. Easiest way: Use the data provided by the author of 'your' posted coded. [Aurelien Geron Hands on Machine Learning](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/tree/master/datasets/housing)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when going through this book. After trying a bunch of workarounds (which I feel was a waste of my time), I gave in and installed the scikit-learn v0.20 dev. Download the wheel [here](http://windows-wheels.scikit-learn.org/) and install it using pip. This should allow you to use the CategoricalEncoder class that has been designed to handle these problems.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem, it was caused by an indentation problem that won't always throw an error (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14046894/3665886).

If you copied the code from the book directly make sure the code is correctly indented.

Answer (score 0):

1. **TypeError: fit_transform() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)**

Why this bug?

**Answer**: because you're using LabelBinarizer() which is [ideally suitable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63822728/5114585) for the response variable.

**What to do?:** You have got a [few options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162855/fit-transform-takes-2-positional-arguments-but-3-were-given-with-labelbinarize/53968899#53968899):

- Use OneHotEncoder() instead
- Write custom transformer for LabelBinarizer
- Use the older version of sklean which supports your code

2. **Difference in the shape of housing_prepared**

If you're using [this data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml/master/datasets/housing/housing.csv), then you've 9 predictors (8 numerical & 1 categorical).
CombinedAttributesAdder() adds 3 more columns and LabelBinarizer() adds 5 more, so it becomes 17 columns
Remember, **sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion concatenates the results of multiple transformer objects**

When you do it manually, you don't add the original 'ocean_proximity' variables.

Let's see it in action:

```
print("housing_shape: ", housing.shape)

num_attribs = list(housing_num)
cat_attribs = ["ocean_proximity"]

DFS=DataFrameSelector(num_attribs)
a1=DFS.fit_transform(housing)

print('Numerical variables_shape: ', a1.shape)

imputer=SimpleImputer(strategy='median')
a2=imputer.fit_transform(a1)

a2.shape
```

**Same as a1.shape**

```
CAA=CombinedAttributesAdder()
a3=CAA.fit_transform(a2)
SS=StandardScaler()
a4=SS.fit_transform(a3) # added 3 variables
print('Numerical variable shape after CAA: ', a4.shape, '\n')

DFS2=DataFrameSelector(cat_attribs)
b1=DFS2.fit_transform(housing)

print("Categorical variables_shape: ", b1.shape)

LB=LabelBinarizer()
b2=LB.fit_transform(b1) # instead of one column now we have 5 columns
print('categorical variable shape after LabelBinarization: ', b2.shape)
```

**4 columns increased**

```
print(b2)

result=np.concatenate((a4,b2),axis=1)
print('final shape: ', result.shape, '\n') # Final shape
```

**NOTE: transformed columns (results of a4) and binarized columns (result of b2) are not yet added to original dataframe.
To do so, you need to convert numpy array b2 to a data frame**

```
new_features = pd.DataFrame(a4)
new_features.shape

ocean_cat = ['<1H OCEAN', 'INLAND', 'NEAR OCEAN', 'NEAR BAY', 'ISLAND']
ocean_LabelBinarize = pd.DataFrame(b2, columns=[ocean_cat[i] for i in 
range(len(ocean_cat))])

ocean_LabelBinarize

housing_prepared_new = pd.concat([new_features, ocean_LabelBinarize], 
axis=1)

print('Shape of new data prepared by above steps', 
housing_prepared_new.shape)
```

When we use pipeline it keep the original (ocean_proximity) variable too and the newly created binarize columns too