# Type error: fit() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, jupyter

I am getting this error while working on question 4 (Chapter 2) from the "Hands on Machine learning" book. This is the question "Try creating a single pipeline that does the full data preparation plus the final prediction". The solution is available in Github link, but the solution is giving me the error mentioned in the title. I used the housing data for my example. Please help me.

I wrote this command and it fired the following error:

```
prepare_select_and_predict_pipeline = Pipeline([
('preparation', full_pipeline),
('feature_selection', TopFeatureSelector(feature_importances, k)),
('svm_reg', SVR(**rnd_search.best_params_))
])

prepare_select_and_predict_pipeline.fit(housing,housing_labels)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: fit() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I would like to attach the solution from Github
[Solution of Question 2 from Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu0JS.png)

But this isn't working for me. :(

Comment: can you upload the full code?

Comment: A bit late to the party, but if it helps, check out: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162855/fit-transform-takes-2-positional-arguments-but-3-were-given-with-labelbinarize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162855/fit-transform-takes-2-positional-arguments-but-3-were-given-with-labelbinarize)

Answer (score 3):

Warning, I'm going to grossly simplify here, but I hope this will help.

In Python, if you call a function on an object, the object itself is always passed as the first argument (unless it is a static or class method). This is usually captured by a parameter we call `self`.

So, if you call `object.function()`, you are passing an argument to `function`, namely `object` itself.

```
class C:
    def f(self):
        print(self)

o = C()
o.f()         # <__main__.C object at 0x7f1049993f28>
o.f('hello')  # TypeError: f() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

In your case, you are calling `prepare_select_and_predict_pipeline.fit(housing, housing_labels)`, so you are passing the function `fit` **three** arguments: `prepare_select_and_predict_pipeline`, `housing` and `housing_labels`.

If you check the definition of the `fit` method, you will probably find that it indeed only takes **two** arguments. I'm guessing the first one will be called `self`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information, but can you help me what I should do now.

Comment: To start, remove one of the arguments from your function call. You probably want to either check the documentation or the source code for the `fit` function you're calling.

Comment: Ok. Will look into the documentation. Thank you