# name 'DataFrameSelector' is not defined

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am currently reading the *"Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn & TensorFlow"*. I get an error when I am trying to recreate the Transformation Pipelines code.  How can I fix this?

#### Code:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

num_pipeline = Pipeline([('imputer', Imputer(strategy = "median")),
                        ('attribs_adder', CombinedAttributesAdder()),
                        ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),
                        ])

housing_num_tr = num_pipeline.fit_transform(housing_num)

from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion

num_attribs = list(housing_num)
cat_attribs = ["ocean_proximity"]

num_pipeline = Pipeline([
                         ('selector', DataFrameSelector(num_attribs)),
                         ('imputer', Imputer(strategy = "median")),
                         ('attribs_adder', CombinedAttributesAdder()),
                         ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),
                        ])

cat_pipeline = Pipeline([('selector', DataFrameSelector(cat_attribs)), 
                         ('label_binarizer', LabelBinarizer()),
                        ])

full_pipeline = FeatureUnion(transformer_list = [("num_pipeline", num_pipeline), 
                                                 ("cat_pipeline", cat_pipeline),
                                                ])

# And we can now run the whole pipeline simply:

housing_prepared = full_pipeline.fit_transform(housing)
housing_prepared
```

#### Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-350-3a4a39e5bc1c> in <module>()
     43 
     44 num_pipeline = Pipeline([
---> 45                          ('selector', DataFrameSelector(num_attribs)),
     46                          ('imputer', Imputer(strategy = "median")),
     47                          ('attribs_adder', CombinedAttributesAdder()),

NameError: name 'DataFrameSelector' is not defined
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`DataFrameSelector` is not being found, and will need to be imported.  It is not part of `sklearn`, but something of the same name is available in [sklearn-features](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sklearn-pandas/):

```
from sklearn_features.transformers import DataFrameSelector
```

([DOCS](https://sklearn-features.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html))

Comment: Hey there, thank you for your reply. As I read a bit further, author defines a DataFrameSelector class. It seems to work as I put it above the code I wrote above. But, I get a new error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162855/fit-transform-takes-2-positional-arguments-but-3-were-given-with-labelbinarize

Answer (score 12):

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class DataFrameSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, attribute_names):
        self.attribute_names=attribute_names
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.attribute_names].values
```

This should work.

Comment: It's sometimes good to reference the source: Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn & TensorFlow page 97

Answer (score 6):

If you are following Hands of Machine learning with Sklearn and Tensorflow,
It's on the very next page, A Custom made Dataframe generator

```
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
class DataFrameSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, attribute_names):
        self.attribute_names = attribute_names
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.attribute_names].values
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
class DataFrameSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, attribute_names):
        self.attribute_names = attribute_names
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.attribute_names].values
```

It may work.

Comment: You have to add here appropriate imports of BaseEstimator and TransformerMixin.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are working on a project `California Housing Price Predictions` from the book `Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-learn and TensorFlow`.

The error

> NameError: name 'DataFrameSelector' is not defined

appeared because the is no `DataFrameSelector` transformer in sklearn. To overcome this error you need to write your own custom transformer for this.

In the book, you can find `DataFrameSelector` transformer code on the next page but however I will also copy this code below.

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class DataFrameSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, attribute_names):
        self.attribute_names = attribute_names
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.attribute_names].values
```

`BaseEstimator` and `TransformerMixin` classes are used to inherit `fit()`, `transform()` and `fit_transform()` methods.

Now there is another class `DataFrameMapper` is also available in sklearn-pandas with the similar objective.
You can find detail about this class from the following link:
[DataFrameMapper](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/sklearn-pandas#usage)

Answer (score 0):

You should insert a cell just before your present code cell and then type the following code

`from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin`

`class DataFrameSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):`

```
def __init__(self, attribute_names):
    self.attribute_names = attribute_names
def fit(self, X, y=None):
    return self
def transform(self, X, y=None):
    return X[self.attribute_names].values
```

By this way your DataFrameSelector class will be defined beforehand