# How to identify if Python Threads with Queue are done with task?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading

Here i have `MazeRunner` Class which put all elements of `self.boxes` in queue and run thread on them until all of the queue becomes empty `q.empty()` .

> Here problem is how do i actually identify if my program is done performing threads on all elements which are in queue of `self.boxes` & return `True`.

It looks challenging because `our threads` are in while loop which keep changes based on `self.boxes` length & `self.threads` we defined.
i have tried putting all threads in list and `t.join` them all. But not luck. Any Help?

```
import threading,queue,time 

class MazeRunner:
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = queue.Queue()
        self.boxes = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] ## `7` elements of list
        self.threads = 5

        for i in self.boxes:
            self.q.put(i) ### ADDING Every element of list to queue

        for j in range(self.threads): ### for i in range(5)  threads
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.ProcessQueue)
            t.start() ### Started `5` threads on `7` elements

    def ProcessQueue(self):
        while not self.q.empty():
            each_element = self.q.get()
            self.SleepFunction(each_element)
            self.q.task_done()

    def SleepFunction(self,each_element):
        print("STARTING : ",each_element)
        time.sleep(10)
        print("DONE : ",each_element)
```

---

```
lets_try = MazeRunner()
if lets_try == True:
     print("All Threads Done on Elements")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait until all threads are done calling [`Thread.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join):

*HOWTO:*

- Replace your `self.threads = 5` expression with class constant:

  ```
  THREAD_NUM = 5
  ```
- Put additional attribute `threads` (for a list of threads) into your `__init__` method:

  ```
  ...
  self.threads = []
  ```
- Put each created thread into `threads` list:

  ```
  for j in range(self.THREAD_NUM):
      t = threading.Thread(target=self.ProcessQueue)
      self.threads.append(t)
      t.start()
  ```
- Define method like `check_completed` to ensure all threads are terminated (done):

  ```
  ....

  def check_completed(self):
      for t in self.threads:
          t.join()
      return True
  ```

The way you need to check "all done":

```
m_runner = MazeRunner()
if m_runner.check_completed():
    print("All Threads Done on Elements")
```

Comment: Thanks Roman,  How do i get the  return `True` ?  , `AttributeError: 'MazeRunner' object has no attribute 'check_completed'` `lets_try = MazeRunner()
print(lets_try.check_completed())`

Comment: Solved : Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094713/getting-an-attributeerror-class-has-no-attribute-method

Comment: @ArbazzHussain, see my update (the way you need to check your threads done)